# Loading the results of an AJAX json response into a select box using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django

Can anyone please assist to load the results of an AJAX json response into a select box using jquery?
I have my code below

```
function filter_sector() {
    console.log("sector selection has started!") // sanity check
    console.log($('#sector_is').val())
    $.ajax({
        url : "", 
        type : "GET", 
        data : { sector_is : $('#sector_is').val() }, 

        // handle a successful response
        success : function(json) {
            result = json;
            console.log(result); // log the returned json to the console  
            $.each(result[0], function(key, value){
                $('select[name=main-industry_group]').append('<option value="' + this.key + '">' + this.value +'</option>');
            });
            console.log("success"); // another sanity check
        }
    });
};
```

From the console output, the result is: 
**`Object {561: "Administrative and Support Services", 562: "Waste Management and Remediation Services"}`**
The console shows an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to put quotation marks around `sector_is` on the `data:` line.

Answer (score 2):

Your result isn't an array, so `result[0]` is undefined.  Instead of `$.each(result[0],...` I think you should use a for loop:

```
for ( var key in result ) {
    var value = result[key];
    $('select[name=main-industry_group]').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value +'</option>');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly. And for the explanation. How would I go about creating an array to use my original code?